# Calculate percentage of count for a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Simple problem, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I want to calculate the percentage a number occurs in a list of arrays and output this percentage accordingly.
I have a list of arrays which looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Create some data   
listvalues = []

arr1 = np.array([0, 0, 2])
arr2 = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
arr3 = np.array([0, 2, 2])

listvalues.append(arr1)
listvalues.append(arr2)
listvalues.append(arr3)

listvalues
>[array([0, 0, 2]), array([1, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 2, 2])]
```

Now I count the occurrences using collections, which returns a a list of collections.Counter:

```
import collections 

counter = []
for i in xrange(len(listvalues)):
    counter.append(collections.Counter(listvalues[i]))

counter
>[Counter({0: 2, 2: 1}), Counter({1: 2, 2: 2}), Counter({0: 1, 2: 2})]
```

The result I am looking for is an array with 3 columns, representing the value 0 to 2 and len(listvalues) of rows. Each cell should be filled with the percentage of that value occurring in the array:

```
# Result
66.66    0      33.33
0        50     50
33.33    0      66.66
```

So 0 occurs 66.66% in array 1, 0% in array 2 and 33.33% in array 3, and so on..

What would be the best way to achieve this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach -

```
# Get lengths of each element in input list
lens = np.array([len(item) for item in listvalues])

# Form group ID array to ID elements in flattened listvalues
ID_arr = np.repeat(np.arange(len(lens)),lens)

# Extract all values & considering each row as an indexing perform counting
vals = np.concatenate(listvalues)
out_shp = [ID_arr.max()+1,vals.max()+1]
counts = np.bincount(ID_arr*out_shp[1] + vals)

# Finally get the percentages with dividing by group counts
out = 100*np.true_divide(counts.reshape(out_shp),lens[:,None])
```

Sample run with an additional fourth array in input list -

```
In [316]: listvalues
Out[316]: [array([0, 0, 2]),array([1, 1, 2, 2]),array([0, 2, 2]),array([4, 0, 1])]

In [317]: print out
[[ 66.66666667   0.          33.33333333   0.           0.        ]
 [  0.          50.          50.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 33.33333333   0.          66.66666667   0.           0.        ]
 [ 33.33333333  33.33333333   0.           0.          33.33333333]]
```

Comment: Works perfect and is quick! Thanks for your answer, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package has a utility function for this, called count_table, which can be used to solve your problem efficiently as such:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
idx = [np.ones(len(a))*i for i, a in enumerate(arrs)]
(rows, cols), table = npi.count_table(np.concatenate(idx), np.concatenate(arrs))
table = table / table.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
print(table * 100)
```

Comment: Thanks! I like your quick and elegant solution, however the result I get is just 0 and 1, not the actual percentages. I tried both integer and float arrays as input, but the result is the same. Any solution?

Comment: works on my machine; win py35 numpy 1.10. make sure to cast to float before dividing, that should solve it regardless of platform

Comment: True, I used an float as input (the array) but forgot to convert the table to float. Working good now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of all values and then simply iterate over the individual arrays to get the percentages:

`values = set([y for row in listvalues for y in row])
print [[(a==x).sum()*100.0/len(a) for x in values] for a in listvalues]`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with the percentages with the following code :

```
percentage_list = [((counter[i].get(j) if counter[i].get(j) else 0)*10000)//len(listvalues[i])/100.0 for i in range(len(listvalues)) for j in range(3)]
```

After that, create a np array from that list :

```
results = np.array(percentage_list)
```

Reshape it so we have the good result :

```
results = results.reshape(3,3)
```

This should allow you to get what you wanted.
This is most likely not efficient, and not the best way to do this, but it has the merit of working.

Do not hesitate if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! However the output does not seem to be correct. I get values of 266 in my example

Comment: Are you using python2.x ? With Python3.4.2, I get `array([[ 66.66,   0.  ,  33.33],[  0.  ,  50.  ,  50.  ],[ 33.33,   0.  ,  66.66]])` for the value of results

Comment: I am using python2.x indeed. This is my output of percentage_list: `[33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 166, 0, 266, 33, 0, 33, 25, 0, 50, 100, 0, 33]`. Is it because of python2.x?

Comment: Well, using python 2.7.9, I get `[66, 0, 33, 0, 50, 50, 33, 0, 66]` as output of `percentage_list`. In python 2.x, the result of a division of int is always an int, while it can be float in python 3.x (removing everything after the comma). Dividing by `100.0` instead of `100` allows to bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use functional-paradigm to resolve this problem. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pprint
>>> 
>>> arr1 = np.array([0, 0, 2])
>>> arr2 = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> arr3 = np.array([0, 2, 2])
>>> 
>>> arrays = (arr1, arr2, arr3)
>>> 
>>> u = np.unique(np.hstack(arrays))
>>> 
>>> result = [[1.0 * c.get(uk, 0) / l
...            for l, c in ((len(arr), dict(zip(*np.unique(arr, return_counts=True))))
...            for arr in arrays)] for uk in u]
>>> 
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
[[0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.3333333333333333],
 [0.0, 0.5, 0.0],
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666]]
```